# What is causing the cups to lift up?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I came across [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextfuckinglevel/comments/t8po3c/this_guy_is_filthy_with_glasses/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) video on Reddit, and as you can see the guy is spinning one cup by putting it into another, and then blowing on it, and the cups lift up. Some are saying its Magnus effect, that it is happening, but will the Magnus effect not be in the direction perpendicular to the axis of rotation than parallel to it, lifting it up?
can anyone explain what is the phenomena that are involved in this, also why does blowing on top of the cup lifts it up? is it that, the air goes through the junction of contact between the two cups and creates some hydraulic pressure at the bottom!

Comment: Take a look at this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344897/how-does-this-cup-with-a-cylinder-inside-puzzle-work  I was given one of these for my birthday just 2 days ago. I think the answer is probably the same.  The reduced pressure across the top.

Comment: You should add a diagram to your question. Stack Exchange questions must be self-contained. They may link to supporting information, but the question needs to be understandable without the links.